# MarkerWithLabel show only last value in the google map api when using Geocoder()

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

When I add marker with MarkerWithLabel it shows the different markers, but the value associated with contains the last value from the data.. like in each marker when writing code `labelContent:building.value` and  `title:building.Country_Name`, it shows the last country name in each maker position like Nepal it shows the last value from data like.. 63 in this condition. I have below JSON format data.

```
       var recipient_country = [{"Country_Name": "MYANMAR", "value": 123},
       {"Country_Name": "MONGOLIA", "value": 11},
       {"Country_Name": "ZIMBABWE", "value": 22},
       {"Country_Name": "Bahrain", "value": 45},
       {"Country_Name": "Nepal", "value": 63}];



  for(var i= 0; i < recipient_country.length; i++) {
        console.log(i);
        var building = recipient_country[i];
        console.log(building.Country_Name);

        geocoder.geocode({'address':building.Country_Name}, function(results,status){
          console.log(results);
          if(status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK){
            var marker = new MarkerWithLabel({
              position:results[0].geometry.location,
              title:building.Country_Name,

              map:map,
              labelContent:building.value,
              labelAnchor:new google.maps.Point(6,22),
              labelClass:"labels",
              labelInBackground:false,
              icon:"circle2.png"
            });
             console.log(building.Country_Name)
          }
          else{
                 console.log("Geocode was not  succcessful for the following reason:" + status);
             }
        });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `geocoder.geocode()` function is asynchronous, and since there's no special scope in a `for` loop the `building` variable is overwritten on each iteration leaving you with the last value iterated when the `geocode()` function executes at a later time.

You have to lock in the value with a new scope :

```
for (var j = 0; j < recipient_country.length; j++) {
    (function(i) {
        var building = recipient_country[i];

        geocoder.geocode({
            'address': building.Country_Name
        }, function (results, status) {
            console.log(results);
            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                var marker = new MarkerWithLabel({
                    position: results[0].geometry.location,
                    title: building.Country_Name,

                    map: map,
                    labelContent: building.value,
                    labelAnchor: new google.maps.Point(6, 22),
                    labelClass: "labels",
                    labelInBackground: false,
                    icon: "circle2.png"
                });
                console.log(building.Country_Name)
            } else {
                console.log("Geocode was not  succcessful for the following reason:" + status);
            }
        });
    })(j);
}
```

Comment: if i want to show the Nepal = 63 in title  than i did  in title: building.Country_Name = +"building.value", but it says InvalidValueError: setTitle: not a string..how can get title with country_name and equals it value